# Header with graphical page number outside the body of the text

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, width

I am formatting a book using LuaLaTex.
I need to obtain headers like
[image]
and
[image]
and I am using the titlesec package.
I need therefore that the page numbers are outside the standard \textwidth.
So far the best I could do is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Apollo MT}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}% environment for colored and framed text boxes with a heading line

\usepackage[vcentering, hcentering, inner=10.5mm,outer=10.5mm,top=25.5mm, bottom=25.5mm,showframe]{geometry} % Extended page layout customization
\geometry{papersize={189mm,246mm}} % Possible dimensions of textbook pages

 %Page headers
%colored box for page numbers
\newtcbox{\mypagenum}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=1pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  colframe=red,coltext=black,colback=white, halign = right,
    width=2.55cm,arc=3.5mm, sharp corners=west, boxsep=2mm,
  } 


\newpagestyle{main}{
   \sethead[][][\thesection~\sectiontitle~\mypagenum\thepage]  % even
           {\mypagenum\thepage Chapter \thechapter\chaptertitle}{}{} % odd
           }
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My title}
\lipsum[20-30]
\section{My Section}
\lipsum[20-30]
\end{document}
```

and I cannot find a (simple) way to extend the header width or position the page number with something like \hspace{-XXcm}.

Comment: Just two questions: don't you think the page numbers should  be at the outer margin? And the \tcboxes should be symmetrical  w.r.t.  a vertical axis for even and odd pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the `\widenhead*` command from`titleps`, and two symmetrical  `\tcbox`es:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Apollo MT}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}% environment for colored and framed text boxes with a heading line

\usepackage[vcentering, hcentering, inner=10.5mm,outer=10.5mm,top=25.5mm, bottom=25.5mm,showframe]{geometry} % Extended page layout customization
\geometry{papersize={189mm,246mm}} % Possible dimensions of textbook pages

 %Page headers
%colored box for page numbers
\newtcbox{\mypagenum}{enhanced, nobeforeafter, tcbox raise base, boxrule=1pt, top=0mm, bottom=0mm,
  colframe=red, coltext=black, colback=white, halign = right,
    width=2.55cm, arc=3.5mm, sharp corners=west, boxsep=2mm,
  }

\newtcbox{\mypagenumb}{enhanced, nobeforeafter, tcbox raise base, boxrule=1pt, top=0mm, bottom=0mm,
  colframe=red, coltext=black, colback=white, halign=right,
    width=2.55cm, arc=3.5mm, sharp corners=east, boxsep=2mm,
  }

\newpagestyle{main}{%
\widenhead*{0cm}{\dimexpr 1cm+1.5pt}
   \sethead[\mypagenum\thepage~Chapter\,\thechapter\enspace\chaptertitle][][] % even
           {}{}{\thesection~\sectiontitle~\mypagenumb\thepage} % odd
           }
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My title}
\lipsum[20-30]
\section{My Section}
\lipsum[20-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]